# playing a multiple videos in windows sidebar gadget

Tags: actionscript-3, sidebar, windows-desktop-gadgets

How to play a multiple videos by using actionscript in a windows sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

The 64 bit Sidebar is the default one. Flash does not run in 64 bit browsers.
You should disable the 64 bit Sidebar and load the 32 bit one instead.